# Invalid continuation byte saving cipher

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following function to create cipher text and then save it:

```
def create_credential(self):
    des = DES.new(CIPHER_N, DES.MODE_ECB)
    text = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')[:16]
    cipher_text = des.encrypt(text)
    return cipher_text      

def decrypt_credential(self, text):
    des = DES.new(CIPHER_N, DES.MODE_ECB)
    return des.decrypt(text)

def update_access_credentials(self):
    self.access_key = self.create_credential()
    print repr(self.access_key) # "\xf9\xad\xfbO\xc1lJ'\xb3\xda\x7f\x84\x10\xbbv&"
    self.access_password = self.create_credential()
    self.save()
```

And I will call:

```
>>> from main.models import *
>>> u=User.objects.all()[0]
>>> u.update_access_credentials()
```

And this is the stacktrace I get:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 738: invalid start byte
```

Why is this occurring and how would I get around it?

Comment: What is the *full* traceback? It looks like you are trying to store a byte string value where unicode is expected, so an implicit decoding takes place. Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: You are storing a bytestring into a Unicode database field, so it'll try and decode to Unicode. Either decode explicitly (latin-1 maps bytes one-on-one to Unicode codepoints) or wrap your data into a representation that can be stored as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing a bytestring into a Unicode database field, so it'll try and decode to Unicode.

Either use a database field that can store opaque binary data, decode explicitly to Unicode (latin-1 maps bytes one-on-one to Unicode codepoints) or wrap your data into a representation that can be stored as text.

For Django 1.6 and up, use a [`BinaryField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield), for example. For earlier versions, using a binary-to-text conversion (such as Base64) would be preferable over decoding to Latin-1; the result of the latter would not give you meaningful textual data but Django may try to display it as such (in the admin interface for example).

Answer (score 1):

It's occurring because you're attempting to save non-text data in a text field. Either use a non-text field instead, or encode the data as text via e.g. Base-64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Using `base64` encoding and decoding here fixed this:

```
import base64

def create_credential(self):
    des = DES.new(CIPHER_N, DES.MODE_ECB)
    text = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','')[:16]
    cipher_text = des.encrypt(text)
    base64_encrypted_message = base64.b64encode(cipher_text)
    return base64_encrypted_message     

def decrypt_credential(self, text):
    text = base64.b64decode(text)
    des = DES.new(CIPHER_N, DES.MODE_ECB)
    message = des.decrypt(text)
    return message
```